# Works in Prompt but not in Eclipse, (Setting Includes and parameters in Eclipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse

I can easily compile my file *Banco.cpp* with the following commands, but I can't do with in Eclipse:

In Prompt:

> C:\Users\Jonathas\workspace\Banco\src>g++ -I "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\include" -L "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\lib" -lpq -o Banco Banco.cpp

I'm going to:

> Project>Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings>GCC C++ Compiler>Miscellaneous>Other flags>

and type:

> -I "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\include" 
>   -L "C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\9.4\lib" -lpq

But this doesn't work.

Error:

g++ -O2 -g -Wall -I "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\include" -L "C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\9.4\lib" -lpq -o "src\Banco.o" "..\src\Banco.cpp" c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/‌​bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpq collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I just want compile it in Eclipse...

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean? What errors are you seeing? Isn't there a way to get Eclipse to show the command line arguments it's passing to the compiler?

Comment: g++ -O2 -g -Wall -I "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\include" -L "C:\\ProgramFiles\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\lib" -lpq -o "src\\Banco.o" "..\\src\\Banco.cpp" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpq
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I just want compile it in eclipse... C:\Users\Jonathas\workspace\Banco\src>g++ -I "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\include" -L "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\lib" -lpq -o Banco Banco.cpp, but i dont know how to configure it...

Comment: Please click the edit button under the question and add the additional info in there instead of the comments.

Comment: Try adding the `-L ...` and `-lpq` flags to the linker settings instead of compiler settings.

Comment: Where can i find linker settings?